# Drawing Great Circles with SimpleKML

Tags: python, kml, google-earth, simplekml

I've just been trying to draw some lines on Google Earth using point coordinates and everything works but for a tiny detail. The lines go through the earth and don't follow the surface so they are usually invisible as I've got points all arround the globe. Any ideas?

```
line = kml.newlinestring(coords=[firstcoord, secondcoord])
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable [tesselate](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#tessellate) on the line geometry to follow the curvature of the earth.

> Very large lines should enable tessellation so that
> they follow the curvature of the earth (**otherwise, they may go
> underground and be hidden**).

To enable tessellation, the value for `<altitudeMode>` must be *clampToGround* or *clampToSeaFloor* otherwise tessellation flag will be ignored.

Make sure the generated KML output looks something like this:

```
  <Placemark>
    <name>line with tessellation</name>
    <LineString>
      <tessellate>1</tessellate>
      <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
      <coordinates>
        -122.383103,37.617112 -73.782201,40.643612 
      </coordinates>
    </LineString>
  </Placemark>
```

Python code to do this:

```python
import simplekml

kml = simplekml.Kml()
firstcoord = (-122.383103, 37.617112)
secondcoord = (-73.782201, 40.643612)
line = kml.newlinestring(tessellate=1,
                         altitudemode=simplekml.AltitudeMode.clamptoground,
                         coords=[firstcoord, secondcoord])

print("Output: line.kml")
kml.save("line.kml")
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that perfectly worked. While I haven't seen the tesselation inside SimpleKML I just add it to every line scripting over the file. Much thanks Jason! :)